# Particle.io flasher not seeing Electron in DFU mode

Tags: particle.io

This is probably a USB drivers problem:

- Particle.io Electron board is in DFU mode (shows blinking yellow LED)
- USB connection to Win7
- particle tool does not see Electron, even after unplugging and re-plugging in the device's USB cable.  Reports the following:

  $ particle update

  !!! I was unable to detect any devices in DFU mode...

  > Your device will blink yellow when in DFU mode.
  >   If your device is not blinking yellow, please:

  1) Press and hold both the RESET/RST and MODE/SETUP buttons simultaneously.

  2) Release only the RESET/RST button while continuing to hold the MODE/SETUP but
  ton.

  3) Release the MODE/SETUP button once the device begins to blink yellow.

Answer (score 0):

solution: need to point Windows at the correct USB driver

https://community.particle.io/t/tutorial-installing-dfu-driver-on-windows-24-feb-2015/3518

Answer (score 0):

Basically the particle Electron 2G should be free from any network restrictions. If it doesn't work in safe mode then completely reset the device --> put the device in safe mode -->then back to DFU mode by installing the driver and continue your work. Use particle workbench for feasibility and a better understanding of device connectivity.